# generate random numbers between 0 and 1 in 10 cells in the row , in which the sum of the random number always equal to 7

Tags: excel

How can I generate random numbers 0 or 1 in 10 cells in the row, in which the sum  of the random number is always equal to 7?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0JK2.png)

Comment: You probably need to write a VB script for this purpose.

Comment: Having a constraint that the sum is always 7 makes the set of numbers non-random.

Comment: @DavidP - No, it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidP - It appears that the constraint of values between 0 and 1 does though.

Comment: @Enigmativity You're right, I suppose you could fairly easily have a set of random numbers and just scale them so they sum to 7 while still remaining random. But if you want your random numbers to be in a specified range AND have a specific sum, I'm not sure they're still technically random. They can however be close enough to random for most purposes.

Comment: @Bathsheba I found the first version much easier in fact, but deleted that version because it didn't seem to be what was required! The key for the '0 or 1' version is to put 1's in the first 7 of 10 cells but then to randomise the order of the cells via rand() + rankings + vlookup as used in my current answer below.

Comment: @MandyShaw Of course that’s the way. Why did I not think of that? Upped your answer out of respect!

Comment: @Bathsheba I've added it to my answer and indicated as much on the other (0/1) question. And thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to get seven "1"s and three "0"s in random order using `RAND` and `RANK`

- In `A1:J1`: `=RAND()`
- In `A2:J2`: `=IF(RANK(A1,$A$1:$J$1,1)>3,1,0)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Available here is a version that I really think works! https://www.dropbox.com/s/ec431fu0h0fhb5i/RandomNumbers.xlsx?dl=0

[image: Here's my final version, which I really do think works!]
And here's the '0 and 1' version (sheet 2 at the above link):

```
De-dup  Rankings    Randoms First Cut   Sorted
0.47999002  7   0.479992063 1   1
0.68823003  3   0.688233075 1   1
0.07594004  9   0.075938331 1   1
0.02077005  10  0.020766892 1   0
0.69217006  2   0.692170173 1   0
0.73355007  1   0.733549516 1   1
0.51546008  6   0.515462872 1   1
0.62308009  4   0.623078278     0
0.33033001  8   0.330331577     1
0.561260011 5   0.561260557     1
```

Formulae for columns A-C exactly as before, D is just 7 1's, E is:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROW(E2)-1,B$1:D$11,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: P.S. @BigBen's answer to the '0s/1s' angle is a much more elegant version of what I have put here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a list of **positive** random numbers that add to `7` you can use this following method.

- Enter a `0` in the top-left cell (Blue Cell).
- Enter `=RAND()*7` into the next 9 cells below the `0` (Orange Cells).
- Enter a `7` in the cell below the 9 random values (Blue Cell).
- Copy the 9 random values and paste-special-values over top to turn the formulas into values.
- Sort just these 9 cells in ascending order
- In the cell just to the right of the first random value put a formula that subtracts the cell to the left and one above from the cell to the left (Yellow Cells).
- Repeat this formula down to the cell next to the `7` that was typed in.
- Sum the values in the second column (Green Cell).

[image: result]

That should give you 10 random values whose sum is exactly 7.

The only issue is that getting the values to be between 0 and 1 will take a bit of trial and error.

---

It appears that trial and error may not be practical. It's about a one in 2,710 times that this list will contain only numbers between 0 and 1. Not overly practical. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of brute force, I think I've got a workable solution to the original version of the question which asked for random numbers *between* 0 and 1.

Cells A1 to A9:

```
=rand()
```

Cell A10:

```
=7-sum(A1:A9)
```

Now you have 10 numbers that add up to 7, but the last one is probably not in the range 0 to 1. To deal with that, just recalculate the sheet to generate new random numbers until that last value is within range. It takes about 25 recalculations to have a ~95% chance that one of them will be within range, so it could take a while. A little VBA can do that for you very quickly:

```
Sub rand7()
    While Range("A10").Value > 1 Or Range("A10").Value < 0
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the post, enter this in `A1:J1` as an array formula (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

`=1-(TRANSPOSE(MOD(SMALL(RANDBETWEEN(0,1e12*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))>0))+(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)/10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))),1))>0.65)`

To answer the question in the post title, do the following:

In `A1:J1` enter:

`=RAND()`

In `K1` enter:

`=IF(SUM(A1:J1)<7,(7-SUM(A1:J1))/(COUNT(A1:J1)-7),7/SUM(A1:J1))`

In `L1` enter:

`=IF(SUM($A1:$J1)<7,(A1+$K1)/($K1+1),A1*$K1)`

Fill over to `U1`.

I believe the 10 numbers generated will be identically distributed in [0,1), but obviously not uniformly (I'm fairly certain the distribution does not have a name). The numbers can't be considered independent. A few statistics on the distribution:

Mean: 0.7 (as expected)

The other statistics are estimated from 10,000 simulations:

Variance: 0.0295

Kurtosis: -0.648

Skewness: -0.192

[image]

Comment: what about if i want the numbers generated from random function only 0 or 1 ..
now i have to use RANDBETWEEN ;
also the sum must be 7

Comment: @AnasAlreyahi. Hmm. I see that I answered the question in the post title instead of the question in the post itself. Give me a minute to update the answer.

Comment: @AnasAlreyahi I have both answers now. The sum for either is always 7. The first answer uses either 0 or 1; the second answer uses all numbers in [0,1) (with machine precision, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as drawing a sample of size 7 from the set {1, 2, ..., 10}. The 1s correspond to the numbers chosen for inclusion in the sample. Here is some VBA code which generates such samples:

```
Function sample(n As Long, k As Long) As Variant
    'returns a variant of length n
    'consisting of k 1s and n-k 0s
    'thought of as a sample of {1,...,n} of size k
    Dim v As Variant 'vector to hold sample
    Dim numbers As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp As Long

    ReDim v(1 To n)
    ReDim numbers(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        v(i) = 0
        numbers(i) = i
    Next i
    'do k steps of a Fisher-Yates shuffle on numbers
    For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(k, n - 1)
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(i, n)
        If i < j Then 'swap
            temp = numbers(i)
            numbers(i) = numbers(j)
            numbers(j) = temp
        End If
    Next i
    'now use the first k elements of the partially shuffled array:
    For i = 1 To k
        v(numbers(i)) = 1
    Next i
    sample = v
End Function
```

Used like: `Range("A1:J1").Value = sample(10,7)`